# Getting the Column Length of any Given Field (All Types of Field)

Tags: php, mysql

**Note:** I am currently using mySQL standard functions, not mySQLi or PDO so any solution would ideally not use mySQLi or PDO.

If you are using utf-8 on your table the PHP function `mysql_field_len` doesn't work as it returns values much higher (double or triple the actual length) for certain field types. A known issue.

If you want to try and do this with an SQL query directly, such as

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE table_name = 'xxxx' 
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'yyy'
```

That also fails for numeric fields, returning (NULL) instead.   I'm using mySQL 5.1.73 on a server running Windows Server.  My understanding is that this problem isn't just limited to this specific old Windows build.

So can anyone recommend a bullet proof function or query to obtain any fields length value getting around my two problems as listed above?

Comment: If you can get the length of a numeric field and can tell if the field type is character or numeric, use an `IF()` in your `SELECT` to choose which to include.

Comment: But using just sql queries I don't have a solution to get fields of a numeric type, for which I believe mysql seems to reliably return the NULL for.

Comment: Looks like [you could get `COLUMN_TYPE` field](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/26890) and (in PHP) pull out the number between the parentheses.

Comment: Here's a somewhat absurd query (note, not complete): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/26901

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 1 other option:

```
DESCRIBE your_table_name;
```

Then you only have to get the numeric value from the `Type` column with a regex.

`DESCRIBE` is a synonym of `EXPLAIN` and a shortcut for `SHOW COLUMNS`.

If you only need one column:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM your_table_name WHERE Field = 'your_column';
```

More info:

[EXPLAIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html)

[SHOW COLUMNS Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html)

Comment: Thanks @bitWorking, the regex idea gave me some new ideas. In the end I used SUBSTR which worked as well.  Code show below..

Answer (score 0):

So I worked this out at last.  I used SUBSTR function of mysql to retrieve values between the brackets of the COLUMN_TYPE column within the INFORMATION_SCHEMA...

```
SELECT SUBSTR(COLUMN_TYPE,INSTR(COLUMN_TYPE,"(") + 1, INSTR(COLUMN_TYPE,")") - INSTR(COLUMN_TYPE,"(") - 1) AS temp FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'xxx' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'yyy'
```